# How can I search for questions/answers of a deleted user (given their number)?

Tags: support, search, deleted-accounts

I'm on some (single) SX site, call it foo.stackexchange.com . There used to be a user named JoeUser, with number 1234. That user has left, deleting their account.

Their questions and answers don't disappear, but I do not seem to be able to search for them: `https://foo.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1234` doesn't work.

Can I effect this search somehow?

Comment: [Make searches for user:xxx work for deleted users as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191964/make-searches-for-userxxx-work-for-deleted-users-as-well) already has an answer with a link to an SEDE query for doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) with the following query:

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], OwnerDisplayName
FROM Posts
WHERE OwnerDisplayName = 'user#####';
```

Note that you must know their user ID number and put that where the hashes are, so in your example, you'd have `WHERE OwnerDisplayName = 'user1234'`.

This will return a link to the post by the title of the question and the current display name.

This works because the display name of a deleted user reverts to the default "user[usernumber]" format when the account is deleted.

**NOTE:** If the user account was deleted recently, their username may still be in SEDE, as it takes up to a week to update (updates Sunday evenings).