# Allow to search by user id when user is deleted

Tags: feature-request, search, deleted-accounts

Specifying the `user:<id>` option to the [search string](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame) allows you to search for posts written by specified user. That also includes the [wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911%20wiki%3A1), which are considered community owned (almost everyone could modify them). But I was surprised that searching by user doesn't work for deleted users, despite of the fact that user id is still visible on the user card:

> [image: deleted user]

Could the searching for posts made by currently deleted user be possible? Is there a reason to don't allow it?

One possible usecase is when the user with a lot of useful posts decides to delete your account, and you will be able to search for they posts though.

Comment: Oh ... somebody doesn't want this feature, but why? Too hard to implement? I see you lazy developer!

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but see also [my argument on MSO that CW posts aren't community-owned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306244/why-cant-i-vote-for-my-own-community-wiki-answer-when-explicit-ownership-ha/306311#306311).

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog it seems that real reason to decline is posted in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191964/make-searches-for-userxxx-work-for-deleted-users-as-well#comment598281_191964): *"none of that is pulled into the search index, and even that is partial string searching, not an efficient int match. – Nick Craver♦"*

Comment: Your request doesn't bring in any new counter-arguments to the declining reason to implement this, and it's declined for *technical* reasons.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog I no longer believe that I will hear on SE: "Yes, we need this feature, it is worth it to implement" ... "despite of our imperfect architecture"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Until this gets implemented you can use [this SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/969928?displayname=user218976)

```sql
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , p.score
     , q.viewcount
     , p.creationdate
     , case p.posttypeid 
       when 1 then 
         concat('Question'
               , case 
                 when q.closeddate is not null then ' [closed]' 
                 else '' 
                 end)
       when 2 then
         concat('Answer' 
         , case 
           when q.acceptedanswerid = p.id then ' [accepted]' 
           else ''
           end
         )
       else '?' 
       end [Question/Answer]
from posts p
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) 
where p.ownerdisplayname = ##displayname:string?user218976##
```

When run today your result will look this:

[image: sql result for posts based on displayname]

SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday around 03:00 UTC.