# Users should not be able to wipe their record by requesting account deletion and then recreating the account

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, openid, network-profile, deleted-accounts

Sometimes, suspended users request deletion, which is usually provided to them.

However, if they log in again with the same OpenID, a *new* profile is created (attached to the same network account), with a new association bonus. No traces of their previous incarnation is left (not the deleted posts, nor the suspension record, etc).

In the case that sparked this request, a user was suspended and later self-deleted. He came back to that site much later, and started causing the same problems, asking the same types of bad questions. If the account hadn't been deleted, the first bad question would be a resuspension. Instead, the mods have to go through the intermediate steps of commenting and mod messaging because they don't know that the user has been warned before. In this case, fortunately the mods remembered and re-suspended.

If a user with some record of undesired activity requests deletion and re-logs in with the same network account, the account should be undeleted. Or moderators should at least get an indication somewhere that this is a reincarnation of a deleted account which has received this-and-this mod message before (and whatever other data is needed to ease the handling of the user).

Ideally, [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180011/could-we-have-two-types-of-account-deletion) would cover this, but that one is broader.

Comment: This would be especially helpful in the case of known trolls!

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to just not allow the OpenID of a deleted account to be re-used?

Comment: @Yannis yes, and that is in the pipeline for spam-deleted accounts already. But I think they want to allow deleted users to come back

Comment: @Manishearth Well, then perhaps all we need is for an (CM-only?) option to put some deleted accounts' OpenIDs (e.g. known trolls) in the same trashbin we put the spam-deleted accounts ones.

Comment: So instead of not being able to "wipe their record", you're really asking to maintain participation info, up to an indication of any bad activity/suspension, etc.?

Comment: Aren't there any legal (or moral) issues with this? Are you allowed to keep a record if you wiped an account as requested?

Comment: @Bart This stuff is already retained, to some extent. Not all of the info, of course. Note that the user has only left the _site_, not the network, and has reassociated their account.

Comment: @rene No legal issues. There are various levels of account deletion, but the usual one available to mods (also used in case of requested deletions) maintains a small (non-mod-accessible) record.

Comment: @Yannis that would work, except that the spam system is network-wide, and I'm not sure how such a deletion would affect their other accounts.

Comment: I think that such account should simply get suspended as soon as it's created, until the original suspension is over. And of course, suspension/warnings history available for moderators.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd But what if the user comes back after their erstwhile suspension is over. In this case, a user who was suspended (and then self-deleted), came back a month later, and started causing the same problems. Usually, that means an immediate suspension. But the mods don't have any way of knowing that this user has been warned/suspended before, except memory.

Comment: @Yannis, *"Wouldn't be easier to just not allow the OpenID of a deleted account to be re-used?"* -- but then people who behave badly are encouraged to create a new OpenID account? It seems we'd lose valuable information then. (Sure some are smart enough to do so already; just wondering if we should make it easier for others.)

Comment: Virtually everything else on SE is soft deleted, why aren't user accounts, at least initially.  Trying to keep every deleted account is probably unnecessary, but for users that have a history of causing problems, it would seem to be more of a benefit than a hinderance

Comment: Soft-deletion for users is on our list of things to work on. No ETA yet since there are many issues to work out there, not all of them technical. For one, @Manishearth, you're seemingly forgetting about all the users who delete their accounts who *weren't* suspended and aren't abusing the system in any way.

Comment: @Manishearth I did say "And of course, suspension/warnings history available for moderators" in my first comment. :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 guess it's related to privacy - suppose you ask to delete your account from Facebook, you won't be happy to know they still have everything you ever wrote stored forever. Anna, am I right about this?

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh, I don't care about them. I don't mind if they're wiped clean, I was focusing on users with some record of bad behavior (for an arbitrary definition of "some", it could be users with annotations, users with deleted posts, users with flagged posts, something.). Edited to clarify

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm not a lawyer, but I believe it's possible to make that sort of thing work. Facebook has two levels of "deletion" - one just deactivates your account, and the other actually blows it away. I don't know what they retain in the latter case, if anything.

Comment: @Anna Facebook being Facebook, you can rest assured they retain everything :)

Comment: @AnnaLear "soft deletion is on our list of things to work on" -- Somehow I missed that. YAY! Should the corresponding feature-request be status-planned? :D

Comment: @Manishearth It's so far in the future that it's too soon for that, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't really think this would be of any help, since creating a new OpenID is 5 minutes' worth of work. However this would contribute to the paranoia about infinitely retaining the personal data without any _actual_ possibility to wipe them. So this brings other issues and solves nothing.

Comment: @Vlad Ah, but then they come back without an association bonus (unless it's a network deletion, and that's rare). Also, for that matter it's trivially easy to bypass many of our other tools (using Tor, etc), but people still get caught by them because they don't think they need to. This won't help catch all users who do this, but it will catch some.  Also, I'm only proposing that we retain the suspension data, and that too only in the case of problem users who request deletion.

Comment: @Manishearth: I agree that retaining just the suspension data is a good thing. If someone wants to really wipe all the memory about himself, he would need to start over with a brand new account + brand new OpenID (which seems to be fair).

Comment: @AnnaLear, any update on when this might be enough on the horizon to count as "planned"?  It's hard to track trolls through the create-suspend-delete-iterate cycle; the workarounds I've seen mostly work but are kludgy.  (When we do notice it, though, I've no regrets about immediately re-suspending if it's within the original suspension timeframe.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Not any time soon. Possibly "never". It is a massive amount of work and we have a long list of other, more pressing things to take care of.

Comment: Thanks @Anna -- I read more optimism into your earlier comment than may have been warranted.  Ok, we'll keep using the methods we're already using; they're not optimal but they're better than nothing.  (Don't want to say too much in public, but you and Manishearth know where to find me for a more-private discussion.)

Comment: This was completed a while back: [Automatically suspend accounts recreated after a moderator deleted the original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277230/automatically-suspend-accounts-recreated-after-a-moderator-deleted-the-original)